# vscode tasks.json shell script doesn't work with arguments

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code

I can't pass arguments to shell script in task.

I work in VSCode 1.36.0 in Ubuntu 18.04. tasks.json version 2.0.0

There is a simple task in tasks.json file:

{
            "label": "cross-deploy_2",
            "type": "shell",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/home/${env:USERNAME}/osr-renesas/"
            },
            "command": ". ./cross-deploy_2.sh",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc" 
            ]
        },

And here is the script **cross-deploy_2.sh**:

```
ip=$1
execution_file=$2
echo $ip
echo $execution_file
. sources/poky/oe-init-build-env
devtool build glv-get-started
```

I need to run it from source in order to save environment variables. So in the previous example I don't see **echo**, but except this script runs properly.

If I add **args**, like this

```
{
        "label": "cross-deploy_2",
        "type": "shell",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "/home/${env:USERNAME}/osr-renesas/"
        },
        "command": ". ./cross-deploy_2.sh",
        "args": [
            "10.15.11.1",
            "glv-get-started",
        ],
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc" 
        ]
    },
```

**The task doesn't work**. And this is the output in the terminal

```
> Executing task: '. ./cross-deploy_2.sh' 10.15.11.1 glv-get-started <

/bin/bash: . ./cross-deploy_2.sh: No such file or directory
The terminal process command '/bin/bash -c ''. ./cross-deploy_2.sh' 
10.15.11.1 glv-get-started'' failed to launch (exit code: 127)

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Please help me to run script with arguments
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `But in this case I can't pass arguments to the script` Why not?

Comment: It is what I get in terminal when I pass args:

> Executing task: '. ./cross-deploy_2.sh' 10.15.11.1 glv-get-started <
/bin/bash: . ./cross-deploy_2.sh: No such file or directory
The terminal process command '/bin/bash -c ''. ./cross-deploy_2.sh' 
10.15.11.1 glv-get-started'' failed to launch (exit code: 127)

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

And without args, it runs properly

Comment: failed to launch (exit code: 127)
And draw your attention, if I run it like "./cross-deploy_2.sh", it gets args

Comment: Does it work if you try ` "command": ".",
        "args": [ "./cross-deploy_2.sh",
            "10.15.11.1",
            "glv-get-started",
        ],` ?  And change your $1 and $2.

Comment: No it didn't work. But I found the problem. The arguments were passed as an arguments to internal script. So I put my script in to the **main**, function, and not it works perfect. ;-)